# How to use user-defined function in Entity Framework Core (Oracle)?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-core

I am just starting to use Entity Framework Core with an Oracle database in a .NET Core 3.1 project and I keep running into problems when trying to call a user-defined function.

The function in the database looks like this:

```
FUNCTION fnc_hourly_data(
    p_quality   IN t_quality_configurations.quality%TYPE DEFAULT NULL,
    p_date       IN DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE)
    RETURN hourly_data_arr_type IS
    v_result   hourly_data_arr_type := hourly_data_arr_type ();
```

I tried to map a method to this function by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping) tutorial so I added this code to the `OnModelCreating` function of the `ModelContext`:

```
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(ModelContext).GetMethod(nameof(FncHourlyData), new[] { typeof(IEnumerable<HourlyData>) })).HasName("fnc_hourly_data");
```

I also defined this function as described in the tutorial:

```
public IEnumerable<HourlyData> FncHourlyData(string quality, DateTime date) => throw new NotSupportedException();
```

When I now execute the application I get the following error:

> System.ArgumentNullException
> HResult=0x80004003
> Message=Value cannot be null.
> Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalModelBuilderExtensions.HasDbFunction(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, MethodInfo methodInfo)
> at ORMTest.Model.HourlyDataModel.ModelContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) in C:\Projects...\ModelContext.cs:line 49
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelCustomizer.Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.CheckState()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
> at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
> at ORMTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projects...\Program.cs:line 14

According to the error, the parameter 'methodInfo' is null here and therefore causes this exception to be thrown but I do not understand what's wrong here.
How do I properly define this function in my project so that I can call it?
Is there maybe another (easier) way to call the function?

Comment: Did you manage to get it working?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not remember this. This was just a demo project that never ended up in production so I no longer have the sources either. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The GetMethod's second parameter is "An array of System.Type objects representing the number, order, and type of the parameters for the method to get".

```
modelBuilder
  .HasDbFunction(
    typeof(ModelContext)
      .GetMethod(
        nameof(FncHourlyData),
        new[] { typeof(string), typeof(DateTime) }
      )
  )
  .HasName("fnc_hourly_data");
```